# How to access active_record database outside of rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using `active_record` database without rails project like this.

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: "posts.db")

unless File.exists? "posts.db"
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.column :title, :string
      t.column :content, :text
    end
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_something
    # do_something
    create(title: title, content: content)
  end
end
```

Now I'm using Firefox add-on `SQL Lite Manager` to access the database.
But if possible I want to access database like `rails console`.

Is there a way to use `rails console` even if only `active_record` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install *pry* gem.
And then in your current project directory add *.pryrc*.
In your *.pryrc* you can add something like this:

```
current_dir = Dir.pwd
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(current_dir)
```

Now, every time you go to pry session just require manually your file such as:

```
pry(main)> require 'models/post'
```

This the simplest method, you can customize or extend from here.